# How to pass an arbitrary iterator as a function argument?

Tags: lua, iterator

###### Question

If I write a generic `walk` routine, why can I pass in my own iterators but not `pairs`?

###### Example

Here's a simple walk that does something for each item in `src`.

```lua
function walk(src)
  for n,i in src do 
    print(n,  i[1]+i[#i]) end end
```

If I call this with `walk(items(x))` then `walk` works fine.

```lua
function items(lst, n)
  n=0
  return function()
    if lst and n < #lst then
      n=n+1
      return n,lst[n] end end end

x={
  {1,2},
  {3,4},
  {5,6},
  {5,6}}

walk(items(x)) --> prints out (1,3),(2,7),(3,11),etc
```

But I try the same with `pairs(x)`, I get a crash.

```lua
walk(pairs(x))
```

```
lua: x.lua: bad argument #1 to 'for iterator' (table expected, got nil)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'next'
    x.lua:7: in function 'walk'
    x.lua:31: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

So what is different about `pairs` and my own iterator `items`?

Comment: The iterator function could return more than two values, btw. For example consider `("aaa"):gmatch"(a)(a)(a)"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pairs` function returns 3 values:

1. The `next` function
2. The table
3. The initial key `nil`

The `for-in` statement uses the 3 values in an equivalent process as follows:

```
local f, t, k = pairs(x)
local v

repeat
  k, v = f(t, k)
  if k then
    -- for body
  end
until not k
```

Since the 3rd value is always `nil`, if you want the `walk` function to be effective on `pairs`, you need at least 2 arguments:

```
function walk(itor, t)
  for n,i in itor, t do 
    print(n, i[1]+i[#i]) end end
```

You need 3 if you want it to be effective on any iterator functions.

Comment: [As of Lua 5.4, `for`-loops even support a fourth "closing value"](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.3.5). (This is important for iterators like `io.lines`, which have to release a resource once the loop is exited (be that through `error`, `return`, `break`, `goto` or whatnot).) You could do `function walk(...) for n, i in ... do` to deal with this (and a fifth value, should it be added in the future ;)) concisely.